# Iterate a function for multiple raster layers

Tags: r, raster, spatial

I am conducting a landscape analysis in R using the 'landscapemetrics' package. I have 208 raster files depicting land cover data, each with the same resolution and CRS but different extents (different geographic locations). I want to calculate the same landscape metrics for each raster without having to copy/paste 208 times. I understand the basics of for loops, but I haven't been able to figure out how to apply them to this specific problem.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: You've got to provide a better minimal viable example to show us what's the setup like to do this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
library(terra)
filenames <- list.files()
for (f in filenames) {
   r <- raster(f)
   # do something
}
```

Or like this

```
filenames <- list.files()
for (i in seq_along(filenames)) {
   r <- raster(filenames[i])
   # do something
}
```